# call useEffect() only when state increases

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to call `useEffect()` but only when the state of `users` goes up. currently, the function gets called on any change to the count whether it increases or decreases. I know I decide when the `useEffect()` gets called in the brackets but I'm not sure how to have it say something along the lines of `users++`.

```
  const [users, setUsers] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('a new user has joined');
    }, [users])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no special way to do this. It always looks for a change, doesn't matter what kind of change it is.

In your case, you can use a function to store previous Ref of users and an if statement to check it. Like so:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState('');

const usePrevious = (value) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
};

const prevUsers = usePrevious(users);

useEffect(() => {
  if(prevUsers <= users){
    // Your logic here
  }
}, [users])
```

Answer (score 2):

Like others mentioned you need to store the *old value* of users count so compare it to the *current value*. `React.useRef` is the best way to go about it. While you're doing it you might as well create a custom `usePrevious` Hook which you can reuse elsewhere. Here is the full solution:

```
const usePrevious = value => {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
};

export const MyComponent = props => {
  const [userCount, setUserCount] = React.useState(0);
  const previousUserCount = usePrevious(userCount);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (previousUserCount <= userCount) {
      console.log('a new user has joined');
    }
  }, [previousUserCount, userCount]);

  return <div>Hello</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hold another piece of state like this `[userIncreased, setUserIncreased]` in your component that changes only if the `users` piece of state increases. So wherever you are calling your `setUsers` function, you check if `users` is increasing or decreasing. If increasing, then call `setUserIncreased` to `userIncreased + 1`. Then you can pass `userIncreased` in your dependency array in `useEffect` hook. (This solution would cause a double rendering since you will be updating your state twice if the `users` piece of state increases.)

```
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(0);
  const [userIncreased, setUserIncreased] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("a new user has joined");
  }, [userIncreased]);

  const handleButton = userNumber => {
    if (userNumber > users) {
      setUsers(userNumber);
      setUserIncreased(userIncreased + 1);
    } else if (userNumber < users) {
      setUsers(userNumber);
    }
  };
}
```